# Extending the delay of an already delay()'d element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an element that is set to fade out after a 1500ms delay. ie: Something like:

```
$("<div>My Element</div>").appendTo("body").delay(1500).fadeOut(400);
```

Is there a way in jQuery to extend this delay period while the element's fading out is still pending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. 
>           Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay.
>       delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, 
>           which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

So I am afraid you can only do it with javascript `settimeout()`.

Correct me if I am wrong. :)

p.s. Just to add that you can cancel the delayed animation using `.clearQueue()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout() {
    function() {
        $("<div>My Element</div>").appendTo("body").fadeOut(400);
    }, 1500
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.delay() probably uses setTimeot() or setInterval().  I'm not sure what effect you are trying to get, but if you want to reset the timer (or restart it), you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/4AevQ/

```
var t;
$('div').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
    t= setTimeout("$('div').fadeOut(400);", 1500);
});

$('div').trigger('click');
```

The code above fade's out the 'div' unless the user clicks on it.